# How to set music file in MusicBobber library

Tags: android

I'm using [MusicBobber](https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber) library in my project. there is no wiki about setting audio uri from `sdcard` or `raw`.

I know in android `mediaplayer` you can set music file this way:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
```

but no idea about this specific library. Is there anyone who worked with this library? How can I tell it to play a song?

Comment: retrive the song from the mobile and then use it as an array

Comment: can u show me a sample code ? @NeelaySrivastava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of getting songs in background

```
class MusicLoader extends BaseAsyncTaskLoader<Collection<MusicItem>> {

private final Uri albumArtUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

public MusicLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public Collection<MusicItem> loadInBackground() {
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
    };
    Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "=1",
            null,
            "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST + ") ASC, " +
                    "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + ") ASC, " +
                    "LOWER(" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC"
    );
    if (cursor == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
    List<MusicItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int title = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int album = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
            int artist = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
            int albumId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
            int data = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
            do {
                MusicItem item = new MusicItem()
                        .title(cursor.getString(title))
                        .album(cursor.getString(album))
                        .artist(cursor.getString(artist))
                        .duration(cursor.getLong(duration))
                        .albumArtUri(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, cursor.getLong(albumId)))
                        .fileUri(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(data)))
                        ;
                items.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return items;
}
}
```

And this is how you can use the arraylist object

```
class MusicItem implements Parcelable {
private String title;
private String album;
private String artist;
private long duration;
private Uri albumArtUri;
private Uri fileUri;

public MusicItem title(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    return this;
}

public MusicItem album(String album) {
    this.album = album;
    return this;
}

public MusicItem artist(String artist) {
    this.artist = artist;
    return this;
}

public MusicItem duration(long duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
    return this;
}

public MusicItem albumArtUri(Uri albumArtUri) {
    this.albumArtUri = albumArtUri;
    return this;
}

public MusicItem fileUri(Uri fileUri) {
    this.fileUri = fileUri;
    return this;
}

public String title() {
    return title;
}

public String album() {
    return album;
}

public String artist() {
    return artist;
}

public long duration() {
    return duration;
}

public Uri albumArtUri() {
    return albumArtUri;
}

public Uri fileUri() {
    return fileUri;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MusicItem item = (MusicItem) o;

    if (duration != item.duration) return false;
    if (title != null ? !title.equals(item.title) : item.title != null) return false;
    if (album != null ? !album.equals(item.album) : item.album != null) return false;
    if (artist != null ? !artist.equals(item.artist) : item.artist != null) return false;
    if (albumArtUri != null ? !albumArtUri.equals(item.albumArtUri) : item.albumArtUri != null)
        return false;
    return fileUri != null ? fileUri.equals(item.fileUri) : item.fileUri == null;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (album != null ? album.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (artist != null ? artist.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (int) (duration ^ (duration >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (albumArtUri != null ? albumArtUri.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (fileUri != null ? fileUri.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MusicItem{" +
            "title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", album='" + album + '\'' +
            ", artist='" + artist + '\'' +
            ", duration=" + duration +
            ", albumArtUri=" + albumArtUri +
            ", fileUri=" + fileUri +
            '}';
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.title);
    dest.writeString(this.album);
    dest.writeString(this.artist);
    dest.writeLong(this.duration);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.albumArtUri, 0);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.fileUri, 0);
}

public MusicItem() {
}

protected MusicItem(Parcel in) {
    this.title = in.readString();
    this.album = in.readString();
    this.artist = in.readString();
    this.duration = in.readLong();
    this.albumArtUri = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
    this.fileUri = in.readParcelable(Uri.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<MusicItem> CREATOR = new Creator<MusicItem>() {
    public MusicItem createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new MusicItem(source);
    }

    public MusicItem[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MusicItem[size];
    }
};
}
```

You can make a getter and setter also if you dont want to pass the array list .
[For more info](https://github.com/Cleveroad/MusicBobber/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/cleveroad/audiowidget/example)